# Refresh Data Android UniversalMusicplayer

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, android-music-player

I am working on Android-Universalmusic player using the source available on [git](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer). So I am using my own json source. Say I have added a new track to the json, how can I refresh the table in MusicPlayerActivity.